# VB.NET newtonsoft list

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Simple problem but seems i cant find a solution.
I have a json reader that needs a json like this :

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "ip": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "name",
    "ip": "0.0.0.0"
  }
]
```

I created a class on vb like this :

```
Public Class main_object
            Public e As New List(Of _subObject)
            Public Class _subObject
                Public name As String
                Public ip As String
            End Class
        End Class
```

My problem is that the output starts with

```
{
"e"[
mylist
]
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Public Class _subObject
   Public name As String
   Public ip As String
End Class

dim e As New List(Of _subObject)
dim x as new _subObject
x.name = "name"
x.ip= "0.0.0.0"
e.add(x)
e.add(x)
Dim jsonString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e, Formatting.Indented)
```

and you will get this in jsonString

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "ip": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "name",
    "ip": "0.0.0.0"
  }
]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.